# How to reset MySQL root user password and privileges

Tags: mysql, passwords, xampp, root, reset

I assigned a password to the root MySQL user in XAMPP some times ago. I recently tried to undo that and give it no password but it's not working.

I tried setting the password to an empty string using `mysqld --skip-grant-tables` and then using the mysql command line directly. It looks like it works, the root user no longer has a password, however if I login in PhpMyAdmin I cannot see any of my databases, only an "information_schema" and a "test" database. If I look at the User tab, it seems to have all the privileges though:

[image]

Any suggestion on how to fix this issue?

Note: I checked with the command line, all my databases and tables are still there, I just cannot see them in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: does your phpadmin use a local address to login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the anonymous user who is allowed to connect from any host. My feeling is that that row is taking precidence over the row for root when MySQL validates the login.

If you have removed that Anonymous user and the issue still occurs, try setting a password to root and the host to `localhost` then connect again.

Comment: Yes that was it - deleting the anonymous user and changing the host to "localhost" fixed the issue. Thanks a lot, I've been struggling with this for days.

Comment: How does the precedence work in this case?  The first row that satisfies the login requirements?